# Setting a random CCColor on a CCLabelTTF

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I need to get a random color between this switch of colors, in order to put it on a label.

```
                label1.color = ccBLUE;

                label1.color  = ccRED;

                label1.color  = ccGREEN;

                label1.color = ccBLACK;

                label1.color = ccYELLOW;

                truckName.color = ccWHITE;

                [label1 setColor:ccc3(160,32,240)];

                label1.color = ccORANGE;
```

Can you give me a hand to do it? I never worked with randoms

Answer (score 2):

Fully Random Color:

```
            [label1 setColor:ccc3(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255)];
```

You can set Some limit also:

```
            [label1 setColor:ccc3(100+rand()%155, 150+rand()%105, 200+rand()%55)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int randColor = arc4random()%5;
switch(randColor)
{
    case 0: default:
        label1.color = ccBLUE;
        break;
    case 1:
        label1.color  = ccRED;
        break;
    case 2:
        label1.color  = ccGREEN;
        break;
    case 3:
        label1.color = ccBLACK;
        break;
    case 4:
        label1.color = ccYELLOW;
        break;
}
```